# Where do tesseract OCR files save to?

Tags: tesseract

I have a question which might be obvious, but I can’t find it in the FAQ or forums. I am using Tesseract OCR on Mac Mojave. I am a new user. Using the following command and seeing the following in the terminal:

```
tesseract /users/SamBell/Desktop/handwriting-test2.jpg out
Warning: Invalid Resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Estimating resolution as 553
```

My question is - where is the output file saving to?

Answer (score 0):

`out.txt` would be saved in the current directory. Execute `pwd` command in the Terminal to display the path to the directory.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)